# unable to create Ingress resource on bare-metal k8 cluster

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

we having an issue while setting up ingress resource on k8 cluster , getting below exception  and need your advise on this regard
Ingress Yaml File

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: web-server-ingress
  namespace: web
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: demo.salimonline.local
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: web-server-service-cluster
            port:
              number: 5000
```

errors while creating ingress resource

```
  Error from server (InternalError): error when creating "ingress.yml": Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "validate.nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io": failed to call webhook: Post "https://ingress-nginx-controller-admission.ingress-nginx.svc:443/networking/v1/ingresses?timeout=20s": dial tcp 10.98.11.87:443: connect: no route to host
```

Allowed Ports in worker nodes

```
10250/tcp 30001/tcp 443/tcp 80/tcp 53/udp 53/tcp 30000-32767/tcp 9153/tcp 8443/tcp
```

allowed ports in Master nodes

```
6443/tcp 10250/tcp 53/udp 8443/tcp 443/tcp 80/tcp 2379-2380/tcp 9153/tcp
```

Ingress controller details

```
[root@kube-master yaml]# kubectl -n ingress-nginx get ingressclasses
NAME    CONTROLLER             PARAMETERS   AGE
nginx   k8s.io/ingress-nginx   <none>       2d14h

[root@kube-master yaml]# k get all -n ingress-nginx
NAME                                          READY   STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE
pod/ingress-nginx-admission-create-w7zw2      0/1     Completed   0          2d11h
pod/ingress-nginx-admission-patch-r25nd       0/1     Completed   0          2d11h
pod/ingress-nginx-controller-84996f6d-nftwz   1/1     Running     0          2d11h

NAME                                         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP    EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
service/ingress-nginx-controller             NodePort    10.111.96.4   <none>        80:31962/TCP,443:30383/TCP   2d11h
service/ingress-nginx-controller-admission   ClusterIP   10.98.11.87   <none>        443/TCP                      2d11h

NAME                                       READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/ingress-nginx-controller   1/1     1            1           2d11h

NAME                                                DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/ingress-nginx-controller-84996f6d   1         1         1       2d11h

NAME                                       COMPLETIONS   DURATION   AGE
job.batch/ingress-nginx-admission-create   1/1           5s         2d11h
job.batch/ingress-nginx-admission-patch    1/1           5s         2d11h
```

Ingress-controller end points

```
[root@kube-master yaml]# k get ep -n ingress-nginx
NAME                                 ENDPOINTS                    AGE
ingress-nginx-controller             10.46.0.5:443,10.46.0.5:80   2d11h
ingress-nginx-controller-admission   10.46.0.5:8443   

        2d11h
```

Answer (score 0):

Ingress resource created after deleting web-hook configuration

```
kubectl delete -A ValidatingWebhookConfiguration ingress-nginx-admission
```